# Converting images to Base64 strings and then replacing each matched image path with the encoded string within a loop, using Python 3 and re.sub

Tags: python-3.x, base64

I'm converting the Markdown below to HTML using Python 3, but before I do that I'm encoding the referenced images into a Base64 string.

I'm attempting to create a portable HTML file with the images base64 encoded so that I can send the HTML without having to explicity include the images as attachments.

```markdown
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet

Image 1:
![](../attachments/image.png)

Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet

Image 2:
![](../attachments/image2.png)
```

The code I have come up with is below:

```py
import re
import base64
import os

# Variables:
folder = "/home/jake/notes/"
note = "note.md"

# Open Markdown note:
with open(note, "r") as note_file:

    # Read note contents into var:
    note_content = note_file.read()

    # Markdown image syntax regex:
    md_img_regex = r"!\[(.*?)\]\((.*?)\)"

    # Find all images in note:
    images = re.findall(md_img_regex, note_content)

    # Actions if images are found in note:
    if images:

        # Loop through regex matches:
        for image in images:

            # Get the basename:
            image_filename = os.path.basename(image[1])

            # Reconstruct the full image path:
            image_file_path = folder + "attachments/" + image_filename

            # Open the image file:
            with open(image_file_path, "rb") as image_file:
                
                # Encode into Base64:
                image_b64_bytes = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
                image_b64_string = image_b64_bytes.decode('ascii')

                # Search and replace image paths tith regex:
                b64_image = re.sub(md_img_regex, f"![](data:image/png;base64,{image_b64_string})", note_content)

        print(b64_image)
```

The code outputs the Markdown in the code block below, and in a process not shown I would then convert it to HTML uysing [Python Markdown](https://python-markdown.github.io/).

You can see the image links have indeed been replaced with a base64 string - so that works nicely, but, it's the same base64 string for each image - it's the base64 string of the final image in the conversion loop.

```markdown
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet

Image 1:
![](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAIAAADYYG7QAAAA0ElEQVR4nOyZMQqDQBBFszPbqClshL1N7pDec+UAOZtguUVaIW0is/kjhmTB/zqXj/tY5TNizDmfakL+LbCGQggKISiEoBCCQoj4ejHdJjOUxqRn3b+Z5/7VnRCFEBRCUAhBIQSFEBRCUAgRPaH5PpvrpTmpNPd4qO6EKISgEIJCiLceSmMyQ6Ue2spwHbQzektasYW+8jX4Ae0UblHdI6MQgkKI3wn1l14avF3w/OtYHou5Lq0ECc68NBLUCK9wDWhb+2lPnx34HXLyDAAA//9Z5hvfisgkAQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)

Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet

Image 2:
![](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAIAAADYYG7QAAAA0ElEQVR4nOyZMQqDQBBFszPbqClshL1N7pDec+UAOZtguUVaIW0is/kjhmTB/zqXj/tY5TNizDmfakL+LbCGQggKISiEoBCCQoj4ejHdJjOUxqRn3b+Z5/7VnRCFEBRCUAhBIQSFEBRCUAgRPaH5PpvrpTmpNPd4qO6EKISgEIJCiLceSmMyQ6Ue2spwHbQzektasYW+8jX4Ae0UblHdI6MQgkKI3wn1l14avF3w/OtYHou5Lq0ECc68NBLUCK9wDWhb+2lPnx34HXLyDAAA//9Z5hvfisgkAQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==)
```

I'm aware that `re.sub` is obviously not working how I imagined it would here, but I'm not really sure how to get it to work the way I thought it would.

I (hopefully obviously) want each image that the script loops over to be replaced with it's corresponding base64 string.

So, it would look like the below.

```
Image 1:
![](data:image/png;base64,eiwfjdsfkjwef...

Image 2:
![](data:image/png;base64,43e8hj9igfdk3...
```

Answer (score 0):

The first line of [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for `re.sub` are a little sneaky IMO. Emphasis added:

> Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost non-overlapping occurrenc***es*** of pattern in string by the replacement repl.

This is specifically controlled by the optional parameter `count`:

> The optional argument count is the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced; count must be a non-negative integer. If omitted or zero, all occurrences will be replaced.

There are a lot of ways the existing code isn't *obviously* correct. Depending how you want it to behave, it's probably *not* correct. Do you want help on the larger structure?